# SAML Auth in asp.net core web Api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication, saml-2.0

I am working on an angular - asp.net core web API project with windows authentication.

We are planning to implement SAML auth in this project.

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp
This article explained the implementation of the asp.net core web app.
What are the changes I need to make in the above solution for the asp.net core web API Or is there any other framework which supports the SAML auth in the asp.net core web app?

Also, the API should use either windows auth or saml auth based on the environment/device.

Comment: I need to implement the same in .net 5 and react. Any solution did you get?